# C. S. Lewis after life with Joy

Tags: c-s-lewis

After the death of Joy, did Lewis ever seriously consider suicide? He mentioned "An overdose of sleeping pills" in *A Grief Observed* but I believe that was written from a strictly academic point of view (CS Lewis, *A Grief Observed* (New York, NY.: HarperCollins Publishers, 1961) p. 29).